# Can you have a returnUrlRequest for a sender view generated from a bulk send?

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I'm trying to create a workflow where a user can do a bulk send through docusign within my application. They would select the clients they want to send forms to for a signature, be presented with a sender view to specify what fields they require, send it off, then have it post back to my application in order to generate emails for embedded signing. However, currently, it doesn't return back to my application after the user has sent off the bulk request despite the return url request being set. Is this currently not possible with a bulk send request?

The following is just some code to generate the sender view url:

```
// Create envelope definition 
var envelopeDefinition = new EnvelopeDefinition
{
    EmailSubject = documentDesc,
    Documents = new List<Document>(),
    Recipients = new Recipients { Signers = new List<Signer> {
        new Signer
            {
                Name = "Multi Bulk Recipient::signer",
                Email = "multiBulkRecipients-signer@docusign.com",
                RoleName = "signer",
                RoutingOrder = "1",
                Status = "sent",
                DeliveryMethod = "Email",
                RecipientId = "1",
                RecipientType = "signer"
            }
    } },
    CustomFields = new CustomFields()
    {
        TextCustomFields = new List<TextCustomField>()
        {
            new TextCustomField() {Name = "Client", Value = _config.DatabaseName},
            new TextCustomField() {Name = "Server", Value = _config.DatabaseServer},
            new TextCustomField() {Name = "DocId", Value = documentId.ToString()}
        }
    },
    EnvelopeIdStamping = "true",
};

// Read a file from disk to use as a document.
byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("test.pdf");
// Add a document to the envelope
Document doc = new Document();
doc.DocumentBase64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
doc.Name = "TestFile.pdf";
doc.DocumentId = "1";

envDef.Documents = new List<Document>();
envDef.Documents.Add(doc);

// Add each recipient and add them to the envelope definition
var recipients = new List<BulkSendingCopyRecipient>();
var recipients = new List<BulkSendingCopyRecipient> {
    new BulkSendingCopyRecipient
    {
        Name = "Bob Ross",
        Email = "bobross@happymistakes.com",
        ClientUserId = "1234",
        CustomFields = new List<string>()
            {
                "A custom field for internal use"
            },
        RoleName    = "signer"
    },
    new BulkSendingCopyRecipient
    {
        Name = "Fred Rogers",
        Email = "mrrogers@neighborhood.com",
        ClientUserId = "5678",
        CustomFields = new List<string>()
            {
                "Another custom field for internal use"
            },
        RoleName    = "signer"
    }
};
var bulkSendingCopy = new BulkSendingCopy
{
    Recipients = recipients
};
var bulkCopies = new List<BulkSendingCopy>
{
    bulkSendingCopy
};
var bulkSendingList = new BulkSendingList
{
    BulkCopies = bulkCopies
};
bulkSendingList.Name = "A document name";

envelopeDefinition.Status = "created";

var envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(config);
var bulkEnvelopesApi = new BulkEnvelopesApi();
var createBulkListResult = bulkEnvelopesApi.CreateBulkSendList(AccountId, bulkSendingList);
envelopeDefinition.CustomFields.TextCustomFields.Add(
    new TextCustomField
    {
        Name = "mailingListId",
        Required = "false",
        Show = "false",
        Value = createBulkListResult.ListId //Adding the BULK_LIST_ID as an Envelope Custom Field
    }
);
var envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(AccountId, envelopeDefinition);

var options = new ReturnUrlRequest
{
    ReturnUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme + "://" +
                HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority +
                HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath +
                "/SIP/ConfirmTagSendAndPublish.aspx?idockey=" + documentId
};

var senderView = envelopesApi.CreateSenderView(AccountId, envelopeSummary.EnvelopeId, options);
var senderViewInfo = new string[2];
senderViewInfo[0] = senderView.Url;
senderViewInfo[1] = envelopeSummary.EnvelopeId;
return senderViewInfo;
```

When the sender view comes up and you hit send it just takes me to the Sent tab in docusign

[What I see after send](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rD41a.png)

Comment: please share your code. The answer I think is "yes" but not 100% sure how you are doing this.

Comment: A few more clarifying questions: Are you using a DocuSign template? Do you want these client users to sign via email (remote) or sign from within your app (embedded)?  The code would be useful.

Comment: @MatthewRoknich I'm not using a DocuSign template. I want the sender to be able to send of the bulk send using the embedded sender view and be redirected back to my app. The signers will be signing within my app through embedded signing. Email alerts will be generated by my app.

Comment: @InbarGazit I've included some code of what I'm essentially doing to generate the sender view url. I'm pretty much setting up the returnUrlRequest in the same way I've done it for just individual envelopes.

Answer (score 0):

So in order for you to do the scenario you're asking to do, you will have to take a slightly different approach:

1. Generate a regular envelope in draft mode with the things you need.
2. Have user interact with it in embedded sending experience.
3. Generate a bulk using the CreateBulkList() method based on the envelope from #2 and the users you add like in your code.

(to do #3 you may need to copy custom fields etc. from the initial envelope to the one used for custom fields)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Currently the envelope gets created in draft mode by setting the envelope definition to 'created', or is there a different way I need to do this? I'm guessing there is a way to make it so that the user can't immediately send off the envelope during the embedded sending experience? So instead they'd be making their changes to the draft?

Comment: the issue is the use of bulk send. Bulk send was designed to send many envelopes. The problem is you're trying to enable the user of your app to send in bulk and that is a bit tricky.